Assumptions on $x$ in indefinite integration: justified or problematic?
I often see people making assumptions about the domain when performing indefinite integration. For instance, in Problems in Calculus of One Variable by I.A. Maron, the following integral transformation is given:
$$I = \int \dfrac{2\tan x + 3}{\sin^2{x} + 2\cos^2{x}}\,dx,$$which is transformed into $$I=\int \dfrac{2\tan x + 3}{\tan^2 x + 2}\sec^2{x}\,dx$$
Clearly, he divided both the numerator and denominator by $\cos^2{x}$, which is only valid if $\cos{x} \neq 0$. This is just one example; I’ve encountered many cases where authors make implicit assumptions about the domain of $x$ when integrating.
Below, I’ve listed a few more examples where assumptions are made, and in some cases, alternative solutions could avoid such assumptions. This raises a question for me: do assumptions about $x$ affect the correctness of a solution in indefinite integration? Given how often such assumptions appear in solutions, it seems unlikely that they invalidate the answers, but it does make me wonder what justifies these assumptions.

$I = \int x^2\sqrt{x^2 -1}\,dx = \int \dfrac{x^2(x^2-1)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,dx$ (assuming $x\neq \pm1$)
$I = \int \dfrac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}\,dx,\quad$Let $x = \frac1t \implies dt = -\frac{dx}{x^2}\quad\text{and}\quad \sqrt{x^2 + 1} = \frac{\sqrt{1+t^2}}{t}$ (assuming $t > 0$)
$I = \int \dfrac{dx}{x + \sqrt{x^2 - x + 1}},\quad$ Let $t$ be such that $\sqrt{x^2 - x + 1} = tx - 1$ (assuming $x \neq 0$)


It is usually okay make assumptions on indefinite integrals. As long as the assumptions don’t contradict with each other, you will get a true answer in some intervals.
However, if you make some contradictory assumptions, you  may not get the correct answer. To avoid this, a convenient choice is to always start with assuming trig functions return positive value (just to simplify the situation if you have multiple different trig functions, not necessary). All common types of trig functions are positive when $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$, which implies that your results are true for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$
If you do multiple substitutions, it might not work in some rare cases. To make sure that it is 100% safe, you can write down the conditions every time you make an assumption. For instance, if you assume $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and set $u=x+ \frac{\pi}{2}$, you now need to be careful that $\frac{\pi}{2} <u<\pi$ and $\cos(u)<0$. Once again, the situations where you have to do this in an indefinite integral is extremely rare, it is usually for definite integrals where you already have some conditions.
You don’t need to worry too much about dividing by zero. For example, $x^2\sqrt{x^2-1}$ is defined at $x =1$, whereas $x^2\frac{x^2-1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ seems to be undefined at $x =1$. However, $x^2\frac{x^2-1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ has a so called “removable discontinuity” at $x =1$. “Removable discontinuity” means you can simply ignore it as if it is not a discontinuity at all.
In general, a discontinuous point is called “removable discontinuity” if and only if its neighbourhoods are the same, namely
$$f(x) \text{ has a removable discontinuity at }x=a \iff \lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$$
Which we recognise as the definition of $f(x)$ being continuous at $x=a$ if we define the following:
$$f_0(x)=\begin{cases}
        L \text{ if } x=a\\
        f(x) \text{ otherwise}
    \end{cases}$$
$f_0(x)=f(x)$ if $f(x)$ is continuous, which means you can replace $f(x)$ with $f_0(x)$ and do whatever you want without any concerns about dividing by zero.

Real indefinite integrals as complex algebraic, differentiable expressions, found  by any way of guessing, transforming, substituting, are a primitive iff the derivative simplifies to the given form or, at least for  analytic functions, the integrated series and the series of the algebraic integral coincide somewhere in the real domain up to constants.
The transformation  and representation spaces are so vast, that a 1-1 chain of the  mappings used in the detection process is not representable on paper even in simple cases.
CAS systems can do it. If  a primitive is found (besides table lookup), in many cases it's representation as a logical expression does not fit in memory.
Hard drive memory has to be used for intermediate storage with the consequence of time consumption like a real Turing machine.
It's nearly a general penomenon in complex nonlinear algebra, that equality of formal algebraic expressions up to a constant poses an unsolvable problem and one is left to compare truncated series and numerical evaluation at a sufficient large number of rational points, e.g. by plotting the difference or calulating an approximation of the Cauchy integral of the difference on a circle in the complex plane.
Finally, with the exception of the small collection of functions integrable  by hand and their images by distortion mappings used as problem set in analysis teaching lessons, 100.000% of randomly generated expressions have transcendent primitives without a name.
